# Display the red marker when returning a value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Custom functions and Document Cache.  Would like to return the red marker in the top right corner if there is a problem, but still display an answer from before that is in the cache.

Example calling URLFetch and had a failure, then accessing the value from before to return and stating there was a failure

Comment: Already able to show the Error message, but gives the cell with #ERROR and actually want to have the previous value. throw new Error("Xero authorisation error, need to reconnect to Xero to get latest data");

Comment: Does it need to be the red triangle in the corner, or would applying a custom background color to the cell be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to have your custom function return an array formula. In the [0][0] index, the normal or cached value would be displayed, while in the [0][1] index, an error message would be displayed.

Example:

```
A2: =MyCustomFormula(A1)

function MyCustomFormula(cell) {
  var oldValue = cache.get("key"), newValue;
  try {
    newValue = UrlFetchApp.fetch(....);
  } catch (e) {
    return [[oldValue, e.message]];
  }
  return [[newValue, ""]];
}
```

This obviously requires a free cell next to / below the cell containing the custom function call.

Comment: Can't do that as this showing a Financial report with values next to each other.  Have built a product linking Xero Accounting to Google Sheets and working to get refined before moving to commercial mode.